# normality of algebraic closure

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

is it always true that $F'|F$ is a normal extension?$F'$ means the algebraic closure of $F$.

what conditions are necessary for that?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

So one of the properties of a normal extension $L$ of $K$ is that every embedding $\sigma$ of $L$ in $K'$ (the algebraic closure of $K$) that restricts to the identity on $K$, satisfies $\sigma(L) = L$. So your question reduces to if every embedding $\sigma$ (which fixes $K$) that takes $K'$ into $K'$ also has $\sigma(K') = K'$.

What is really more interesting is the question of normal extensions that sit in between $K$ and $K'$.

Comment: @Gege sorry i'm weak at English,i didn't understand u.u mean that is always true?

Comment: Yes, (though obviously you should try to convince yourself of this instead of just taking my word for it). One way to think about it is that field extensions are vector spaces over $K$ so a map from $K'$ to $K'$ that is an embedding (has a trivial kernel) also must be surjective.

Comment: thanks see this pls:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999477/necessary-conditions-for-having-a-equatoins

Comment: Also the other way to describe a normal extension $L$ is that polynomials with at least one root in your extension $L$ must have all of their roots in $L$. With the algebraic closure you have thrown in all the roots of polynomials so any polynomial has all its roots.